# If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and $E[Y|X]=X$ almost surely, does that mean $X=Y$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 random variables such that $X\sim Y$ and $E[Y|X]=X$ almost surely. Is it true that $X=Y$ almost surely?

This is true in the Gaussian case and I was wondering if it was true in general.

EDIT: I think I got it if $X$ and $Y$ are $L^2$, can someone confirm?

\begin{align*}
E[(Y-X)^2]
&= E[Y^2]-2E[YX]+E[X^2]\\
&= E[Y^2]-2E[E[YX|X]]+E[X^2]\\
&=E[Y^2]-E[X^2]\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Hence $X=Y$ a.s.

What about $L^1$ ?

Comment: Try applying the law of total variance (at least when $X$ and $Y$ have a finite variance).  I think you will find $\text{Var}(Y \mid X)=0$ with probability $1$, which should give you your result

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/conditional-expectation-and-almost-sure-equality and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel

Comment: I think you might wanna add that they are defined on the same probability space. For finite mean, the above comment resolves it.

Comment: @Henry, When $X$ (and hence $Y$) is assumed to have finite second moment, the proof is easily done by noting that $\mathbb{E}[(Y-X)^2]=0$. So the true obstacle is the case where $X$ has infinite second moment, although the case of finite second moment seems hinting an affirmative answer. I guess we might possibly tweak some of the techniques in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843).

Comment: Thank you all for the $L^2$ case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an argument based on the idea of [**@mathex**'s answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605516):

> **Lemma.** Let $X, Y \in L^1(\mathbf{P})$ be such that $X \sim Y$ and $\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X]=X$. Then, for any $k\in\mathbb{R}$,
> $$ \mathbf{E}[Y\wedge k\mid X\wedge k] = X\wedge k
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \mathbf{E}[Y\vee k\mid X\vee k] = X\vee k.$$

*Proof of Lemma.* We only prove the first part. Let $Z = X \wedge k - \mathbf{E}[Y\wedge k\mid X\wedge k]$. Then

$$ \mathbf{E}[Z]
= \mathbf{E}[X \wedge k] - \mathbf{E}[Y \wedge k]
= 0. $$

So it suffices to prove that $Z \geq 0$. However, this follows from

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[Y\wedge k\mid X\wedge k]
&\leq \mathbf{E}[Y\mid X\wedge k]\wedge k \tag{$\because$ Jensen} \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X]\mid X\wedge k]\wedge k \\
&= \mathbf{E}[X\mid X\wedge k]\wedge k \\
&= X \wedge k,
\end{align*}

completing the proof of the lemma. $\square$

Now we return to the original question. By the lemma, for any $n \geq 1$ and with the truncation function

$$ f_n(x) = (-n) \vee (x \wedge n) = \begin{cases}
-n, & x < -n \\
x, & -n \leq x \leq n, \\
n, & x > n
\end{cases} $$

we get $\mathbf{E}[f_n(Y) \mid f_n(X)] = f_n(X)$. Since $f_n(X)$ and $f_n(Y)$ are bounded, arguing as in OP, we get

$$f_n(X) = f_n(Y).$$

Now we conclude by letting $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Hello @SanghculLee, how does $E[f_n(Y)|f_n(X)]=f_n(X)$ follow from the lemma?

Comment: @Snoop, You may apply the lemma twice :)

Comment: Why is $\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\wedge k]\wedge k= X \wedge k$?

Comment: I think that it works find if you replace all the conditional expectations $\mid X\wedge k$ by $X$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, The reason is that we have $$\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\wedge k]=X\mathbf{1}_{\{X<k\}}+\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\geq k]\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geq k\}}.$$ You may check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657249) for a proof.

Comment: Then I am not sure I follow: I agree with your formula $\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\wedge k]=X\mathbf{1}_{\{X<k\}}+\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\geq k]\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geq k\}}.$ but then this random variable is not equal to $X\wedge k$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, You have to take minimum with $k$ to the above conditional expectation. Note that the equality to prove $$\mathbf{E}[X\mid X\wedge k]\wedge k= X \wedge k.$$

Comment: Ah I missed that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hi @SangchulLee, could you please explain why $f_n(X) = f_n(Y)$ ? I fail to see it...

Comment: @StratosFair, OP already resolved the case where $X$ and $Y$ are $L^2$. What I showed is that $f_N(X)$ and $f_N(Y)$ (in place of $X$ and $Y$, respective) also falls into this case.